# ImportXML Parse Error trying to to pull the lowest BIN (Buy it Now) price for Xbox

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets, xml-parsing

So I'm trying to pull information from this page [here](http://www.futbin.com/player/3149/daniel-sturridge) using the below formula but it keeps giving me a Formula parse error.

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, “//div[@class='prices lowestBin']//span[@id='xboxlbin']”)
```

Does anybody happen to know why this isn't working? I want to pull the lowest BIN (Buy it Now) price for Xbox.

Also, I forgot to mention I have the url input into cell A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.futbin.com/player/3149/daniel-sturridge","//*[@id='pslowest']")
```

or

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.futbin.com/player/3149/daniel-sturridge","//*[@id='xboxlowest']")
```